# A No-Sensa Test Question

Tags: knowledge, pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

What is in the blank box? Why? Pick from one of the five options.

[image]

For folks who don't see colors well

Y = yellow, R = red, O = orange, B = blue, G = green, P = purple

> Grid:
>
> |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Y | R | O |
> | Y | B | G |
> |  | B | P |

> Options:
>
> |  |  |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | R | B | R & B | Y | R |

Comment: Obviously the puzzle is full of colors. I did not think of "color blind" solvers. I apologize. Is there something I can do for that?

Comment: Some of these look kinda like letters… but what do the colors have to do with it!?

Comment: @Someone it has the knowledge tag so presumably they combine to indicate something you can't just know by looking at the picture and pattern but link in some other way.

Comment: "What is in the blank box?" Nothing. You said its blank.

Comment: @Ak. I appreciate your bounty. But I'm ok with ducvu getting the check. He did after all figure out that the last row was chemical elements. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: Very well put @Prim3numbah. Appreciate you saying this.

Comment: @Prim3numbah You're welcome =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> [image]

Credits to @Prim3numbah for

> aptly enough, finding out the sequence is prime

Comment: Aaah, well done! Got stuck on the last row for quite sometime

Comment: Wondrfully explained

Comment: Even though you borrowed heavily from PrimeNumbah's answer that graph is very pretty to look at +1.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is

> Option E

Because

> First to notice is that the first two columns color are added and make the color in the 3rd column.
>  Yellow + Red = Orange, Yellow + blue = Green, **[Red]** + blue = Purple. So we're looking for a red figure.
>  Second to notice is that these are the **prime numbers!** from 2-13 (note, upside down roman numeral, V) , reading from left to right row for row.. So one might think the missing figure should resemble the number seventeen and that the two next entries should represent 19 and 23 but there is no resemblance.
>  Now, here's where the *non-sensa* part come in, I *believe*. The last row could be obtained by converting the number above to it's corresponding letter and then rotate this shape/letter 180 degrees in comparison to the figure above (note that two lines of each letter is missing). In that case we get a "G" by adding two more lines.

Comment: O  So close. Terng ybtvp nobhg pbybef naq cevzr ahzoref. Guvax uneq nobhg gur friragrra, avagrra naq gjragl guerr. Nal bgure cynpr gurl pna or sebz?

Comment: Nice one, I was just about to give this puzzle a go but you already more or less solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> D aka the yellow diagonal [|

Reasoning (color):

> I couldn't help but notice that the 2nd collumn has 2 colors, and the 3rd has 3 colors. D fits this. Further, each row has 3 different colors. A, D or E fit here

Reasoning (shape):

> If you count how many edge midpoints and corner points are contained in each picture, you get {4,4,3},{2,4,5},{__,4,3}. Row 1 & 2 add up to 11. A, C, or D fits here.

> D is the only one that fits in all these patterns.

Comment: hello @Ankit. There is a lot more going on in the puzzle. rot13yrggref, ahzoref, cnggrea